# Creating Lua dissector in Wireshark for non-Ethernet data

Tags: lua, wireshark, i2c, spi, wireshark-dissector

I'm trying to create dissector in Wireshark using Lua script for non-Ethernet data. For example, I captured I2C bus data, converted it to .pcap file format, which can be opened by Wireshark. Each record has one byte of address and few bytes of data. How can I handle this in Lua for dissecting data?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [packet-i2c.c](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-i2c.c;h=5af77db8cc304f6b0a11a55689c7efb056ef2489;hb=HEAD#l258) source file, you will see on line 258 that you need to register your dissector with the *"i2c.message"* table, similar to how it was described in the [How to register a Lua dissector for 802.1Q Ethernet payload](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/54870/how-to-register-a-lua-dissector-for-8021q-ethernet-payload) question over at Wireshark's Q&A site.  So, in your case, something like:

```
-- Protocol
local p_i2cfoo = Proto("i2cfoo", "I2C FOO Protocol")

-- Fields
local f_i2cfoo_addr = ProtoField.uint8("i2cfoo.addr", "Address", base.DEC)
local f_i2cfoo_val16 = ProtoField.uint16("i2cfoo.val16", "Value 16", base.HEX)
local f_i2cfoo_val32 = ProtoField.uint32("i2cfoo.val32", "Value 32", base.HEX)

p_i2cfoo.fields = { f_i2cfoo_addr, f_i2cfoo_val16, f_i2cfoo_val32 }

-- Dissection
function p_i2cfoo.dissector(buf, pinfo, tree)
    local i2cfoo_tree = tree:add(p_i2cfoo, buf(0,-1))

    pinfo.cols.protocol:set("I2CFOO")
    pinfo.cols.info:set("Hello World!")

    i2cfoo_tree:add(f_i2cfoo_addr, buf(0, 1))
    i2cfoo_tree:add(f_i2cfoo_val16, buf(1, 2))
    i2cfoo_tree:add(f_i2cfoo_val32, buf(3, 4))
end

-- Registration
local i2c_table = DissectorTable.get("i2c.message")
i2c_table:add(0, p_i2cfoo)
```